# How may I detect if user redirected by QR Code in React/Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have Next app and simply want to detect if user reached by qr code to website ..

How can I detect it ?

Comment: Just encode in the QR Code url something that tells that the user is using that url, like `?origin=qr` or something that you will know.

Comment: @Ivella Thanks .. By the way i want to authorize and set token to cookie for only those who redirected by qr and prevent any access by typed url link

Comment: You can't. QRCode is just a plain "text" that anyone with a smartphone can read. Once I decode it. I can click it, I can copy and paste it, I can send via text message to someone else, I can type it, etc. and you will never know it. Heck, I can even decode it by hand with pen and paper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA8hDldvfv0